# What's the difference between main() and int main()?

Tags: c

I'm familiar with `int main()` and `void main()`, but I saw that our professor at uni uses `main ()` -just `main()`, nothing else- in his codes, what exactly does it do? I read that it won't work on new C standards, but I tried it on my computer and it worked fine.

Does `main()` return a value like `int main()` or is it more like `void main()`?

Comment: Your professor learned C in the 1980s, probably.

Comment: `void maion()` is not a valid signature for a hosted environment. And all of your examples are ancient and deprecated. If you don't have arguments, use `int main(void)`!

Answer (score 0):

It used to be you could leave them off in C and that would default to `int`, but no more. As for the `main` function. The return type of `main` must be `int`.